# Develop for Android on both Linux and Windows machines at the same time

Tags: android, eclipse

I've currently got two computers. One computer is at home another one is where I work.
On my breaks I like to work on my own projects at work, however my machine at work is Linux.
My machine at home is Windows.

I'd like to know if it is possible to simultaneously work on an Android Java project
on both Windows and Linux?

Clearly I could easily use mercurial or dropbox and just put my work there, but this is not what I'm asking.

What I'm asking is, what IDE can I use that works in both linux and windows, will compile the same way so I won't have to change the code based on what operating system I'm using to compile, will let me achieve this goal?

==SUMMARY==
Will Eclipse work the exact same way as it does in Linux (Linux Mint 16 to be exact), as it does in Windows? Will I be able to save a project in Linux from Eclipse, and open it up when I get home in Windows and continue working on it?

Comment: You didn't say how you're sharing the code. I've had very good luck moving between Mac and Windows. Set up a git repo. Push code from one system. Pull to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse on Windows and Linux will definitely work 'the same way' no matter what. The Eclipse versions are identical, they produce the same results. You'll be fine. 
As you already mentioned, it would be useful to use some version control system to share the code between the two machines, but you can share the code any way you want.

Comment: Is there any down side to using dropbox? I would literally be the only one using the code and I don't use both machines at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use both Eclipse and Intellij (preferred one) in both linux and windows without any additional requirements and problems.